# Should I worry about this 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error? (Rails & Devise)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using ajax to submit my registration form.

[image]

The form submitted correctly when the details are correct. I also able to capture the errors correctly if the details are wrong. But, if the details are wrong, I also could see `POST http://localhost:3000/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` error message on my console log :

[image]

My question is, should i be worried about this error? Or this is normal?
If this is not normal, how should I correctly handle it?

Thanks!

**################################  UPDATE ##############################**

**Error message from terminal:**

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-15 09:20:20 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0D1qSK8IfbuefQ0bwEdKQFD+6WZ8XJtCnl2FZ6Nln9khLtv6qYCmoTKhwBFkVIJdYXSRQJ4e+9QAAdJ5UJzukQ==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "email"=>"ryzalyusoff@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'ryzalyusoff@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 93ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

**Registration controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    super
  end
end
```

**application.js:**

```
$(function(){

  $("form#ajax_signup").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var user_info = $(this).serializeObject();
     console.log("About to post to /users: " + JSON.stringify(user_info));
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost:3000/users",
       data: user_info,
       success: function(json){
         console.log("The Devise Response: " + JSON.stringify(json));
       },
       error: function(xhr) { 

            var errors = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors; 

            for (messages in errors) { 
                error_messages =  messages + ' ' + errors[messages];

                console.log(error_messages);
            } 

       }, 
       dataType: "json"
     });
  });

});
```

Comment: Could you put the rest of the relevant log entry in, and the controller method responsible (including any strong params methods in use).

Comment: Yes, of course you should care and of course some 4xx response is expected to be returned if this POST action fails for some reason ("email address taken"). What do you expect? Do you just want to do client side validation? Even so, you should handle error responses sent by the server in any case...

Comment: @Matt i've posted some more details on the question

Comment: @matthias yes, later i plan to display the errors that I recieve to the user's browser. But I just wonder whether or not the 422 error suppose to appear on the console. Because I have taken a look on sites like Airbnb and check the console when the form failed, but there is no 422 error like this.

Comment: @ryzalyusoff Okay, i see. The answer is: It is absolutely legitimate to send requests and receive response codes others than 2xx. As long as you're handling those responses and five feedback to the user, everything is fine. The user shouldn't care about network status codes of XHRequests. Different status codes for different error types is just the way like REST APIs work and part of the minimum contract a REST client could rely on.

Comment: @matthias ah okay then I got it now. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

No you don't worry about 422 in your console, this red warning will not break your javascript code.
But this error can provide you easy validation handling in your javascript code, like:

```
$('#form').on('ajax:error', 
  function () { return 'handle me'; }
);
```

Comment: Ah yes. I just wondering because, when I check the site like Airbnb (which i believe they use AJAX to handle their registration form), when the form failed, there is no 422 errors or whatsoever. Shouldn't they suppose to show the same errors like mine? Or there is a way to handle this thing correctly

Comment: There's two approaches to handle a validation: first: 422  and second: 200 (ok) + `errors: { name: 'cant be blank' }` in a body. In first way you can check status code, in the second one you should check the body on `error` key presence

Comment: @itsnikolay That is true and probably some big services handle it like this (plus doing a lot of pre-fetching data to check e.g. availability, doing some "predictive" client side validation). But nonetheless, it's way more REST style to return 4xx (client side error) codes if the client side sent data that couldn't be processed in a manner that an entity could be successfully created or updated (POST, PUT, PATCH...).

Comment: checking 422 is also better way, especially when a server can return 500+ errors with a wierd html body. I choose to use 422 way